# await Band to Connect iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, microsoft-band

I am trying to connect to Microsoft's Band from the iPhone via swift with this method:

```
override func Connect() -> Connection {
 MSBClientManager.sharedManager().connectClient(self.band)
return .connected
}
```

When the connection happens, the SDK calls:

```
public func clientManager(clientManager: MSBClientManager!, clientDidConnect client: MSBClient!)
```

I tried putting a `while(clientManagerNotCalled){}`, but it blocks calling clientManager, how can I wait for the method to be called? before returning the connection state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a solution to this situation, so I found a way around:

create a function to be called, with the parameter of connection state.

call the function when client manager calls:

```
public func clientManager(clientManager: MSBClientManager!, clientDidConnect client: MSBClient!)
```